# SQLAlchemy - Handling Constraint Failures

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

With SQLAlchemy, If I have a unique column in my database eg, username:

```
username = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
```

When I add a row that breaks this constraint where the username I’m trying to add already exists, an IntegrityError is thrown:

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) (1062, u"Duplicate entry 'test' for key 'username'")
```

Is it possible to instead map the breaking of a constraint to a custom exception? eg.UsernameExistsError

I want to be able to catch individual constraint breaks, and send a response back to the user. eg: "This username is already in use"

Is this possible? Or what would be the next best thing?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

The next best thing might be surrounding the call with a `try ... except`, parsing the error message, and notifying the user with a constructed error message.

Along those lines, you could `try ... except` the error and return a custom error code with Flask's [custom error pages](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/errorpages/).

Comment: I feared parsing the error would be the only option. Would be awesome if Flask was able to handle things like this...